# TeXshop with shell script setting can't find a program in the shell. Why does this happen?

Tags: texshop, scripts, ps2pdf

Hello people in this site,

I am a newbie to this site, and this is my first question here.
In the Preference->Engine->Latex of TeXshop, I wrote as 
`~/Library/TeXShop/bin/pdfplatex2`
where `platex2` is a shellscript with the description of

```
#!/bin/sh
platex -synctex=1 "$1" && \
dvips -z -f "`basename "$1" .tex`.dvi" | \
convbkmk -g > "`basename "$1" .tex`.ps" && \
ps2pdf "`basename "$1" .tex`.ps"
```

the contents of which have no erroneous parts.

Additionally, I appended the path of `ps2pdf` to the `.bash_profile` which  I don't think is wrong either.

There is nothing wrong, it seems to me, because when I typeset a file with TeXshop, the shell script was certainly read in, 
but a LaTeX error appears saying:

```
/Users/hiro/Library/TeXShop/bin/pdfplatex2: line 5: ps2pdf: command not found
```

I can't understand why TeX can't find `ps2pdf` even though the path has been found.

I will be very glad if you give me a hint about this.

Comment: Is the executable bit set on your script? I.e. in the terminal, do `chmod +x /Users/hiro/Library/TeXShop/bin/pdfplatex2` and then try your script again.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the shell script directly from a command-line?

Comment: Thank you, Alan. I did. And the properties of the pdfplatex2 is 
-rwxr-xr-x now. But, when I typeset it again, the error message 
which emerged is the same one: ps2pdf: command not found

Comment: Thank you remco. I tried executing the script from a command-line, just now. As I have to consider on the result, I will write something  tomorrow morning. It is 1:42 in the night.

Comment: You added to .bash_profile but your script is using /bin/she rather than /bin/bash. Also, have you changed the PATH variable? What does `echo $PATH` give in Terminal?

Comment: > Herb
I changed /bin/bin to /bin/bash now.
And, the output of echo $PATH is 
/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin:/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/hiro:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Applications/MacGhostView.app/Contents/Resources/bings/

Comment: >remco
the result on terminal of directly executing the shell-script is this.
Output .. on test7.dvi
Transcript .. on test7.log
This is dvips(k) 5.997 Copyright 2017 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
dvips: DVI file can't be opened: .dvi: No such file or directory